# How to find out what is taking up my Mac storage?

Tags: mac, storage, osx-yosemite

So when I went to see how much storage I had left I see only 2.55 GB?

This is because I apparently have taken up 100.15 GB of other.

I don't believe this as I just purchased this Mac in July.

Possibly it's a yosemite bug.

How do I find out what other is?

Answer (score 0):

## OmniDiskSweeper

I always use OmniDisk sweeper for answering this question, It has often helped me a lot finding out why my free disk space is so low.

OmniDiskSweeper is Freeware
http://www.omnigroup.com/more

> OmniDiskSweeper is really great at what it does: showing you the files
>   on your drive, in descending order by size, and letting you decide
>   what to do with them. Delete away, but exercise caution. (Requires OS
>   X v10.8+)

There should be also versions for older MacOS X versions available, I'm using `OmniDiskSweeper 1.7.1` it on OS 10.6

Answer (score 0):

There’s also **[Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/)**, a (sort-of) port of KDirStat. It’s quite old but still works perfectly for me. It’s Open Source and free (as in beer).

> Disk Inventory X is a disk usage utility for Mac OS X 10.3 (and later). It shows the sizes of files and folders in a special graphical way called "treemaps".
>
> If you've ever wondered where all your disk space has gone, Disk Inventory X will help you to answer this question.

[image: Disk Inventory X]